# Profiling Server Side vs Client Side Psycopg2 Cursor

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm profiling code to see the difference between bulk load from a Postgres DB source or stream from the source. The design for bulk is `psycopg2` with a client side cursor. The design I'm testing for stream is a server side cursor with an `itersize` of 20,000. The test table has ~600,000 rows.

The "server side" script I'm running is:

```
with psycopg2.connect(dbname=.., host=.., port=.., user=.., password=..) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor("server_side", cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    cursor.itersize = 20_000
    cursor.execute("select * from schema.large_table")
    for i, row in enumerate(cursor):
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(f"Row number {i}")
        if i == 10_000:
            break
```

I expect this to fetch 20,000 rows to the client then iterate over them until it gets to 10,000 and stop.

The "client side" code is:

```
with psycopg2.connect(dbname=.., host=.., port=.., user=.., password=..) as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
    cursor.execute("select * from schema.large_table")
    for i, row in enumerate(cursor):
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print(f"Row number {i}")
        if i == 10_000:
            break
```

I expect this to fetch the whole table (600,000 rows) then iterate over 10,000 rows and stop. This seems like it should be slower because it has to move more data over the network. In practice I see the memory usage of the process grow much higher for the client side solution, but the client side solution runs for 65 seconds and the server side solution takes ~10x as long 619s.

The output for each is the same so I know they're processing the same number of rows:

```
Row number 0
Row number 1000
Row number 2000
Row number 3000
Row number 4000
Row number 5000
Row number 6000
Row number 7000
Row number 8000
Row number 9000
Row number 10000
```

Why is server side slower?

### Edit:

Applying the changes suggested in the comments (`enumerate(cursor.fetchone())` -> `enumerate(cursor)`) results in expected behavior. I updated the code snippets for posterity.

After I fixed the bug in our code which was iterating through every value of every row instead of row by row the client side cursor took ~4.5x longer with more memory used.

Comment: Your code does not match your output.  Calling `enumerate(cursor.fetchone())` will have your loop iterate over the columns.  Try `for i, row in enumerate(cursor):`, instead.

Comment: 1) This `for i, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchone())` can be shortened to `for i, row in enumerate(cursor)`. 2) Have you looked at Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database?

Comment: Your code as shown doesn't do anything, and trying to fix it yields the same text output but can't reproduce the timings (at all).

Comment: @MikeOrganek thanks, you're right, I was attempting to reduce some OO code to a minimal example here, the `.fetchone()` part is being returned in the `_iter__` definition of our class and it's what's causing the problem because we're iterating the row dict instead of the cursor.